# Boolean search with truncated exclutions words don't work for me

Tags: mysql, boolean-expression

When I search for:

```
SELECT * FROM db.test
WHERE
MATCH(story)AGAINST('(+bananas -banana*)'IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get rows returned but when I search for

```
SELECT * FROM db.test
WHERE
MATCH(story)AGAINST('(+bananas -bananas)'IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM db.test
WHERE
MATCH(story)AGAINST('(+bananas -bananas*)'IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get no result. To me it seems like you can´t use * together with the minus sign.
Does anybody know if thats the case or if its a setting in MySql.

Kind regards
Olle

The table is MYISAM and I have a index on the column story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to skip the parentheses. If I search for '+bananas -banana*' instead of '(+bananas -banana*)' it works. It took a while to figure out thou.

Cheers

Comment: hmm, I noticed those parenthesis but I didn't think they will make a difference to the query. I tried myself, the query returned same results with or without the parenthesis because I think ) after -banana* does not mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

The last 2 queries do not give any result because they contain contradicting conditions - story must have the word "bananas" and must not have the word "bananas". This is not possible and hence no results.

However the first query means that "bananas" must be present but no "banana".

Also, you may use * with the minus operator.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe that the first row should not return any rows either since I search for bananas not banana*; and banana* matches bananas, bananaleaf bananaboat and so on. And that my problem I get rows when I truncate the exclusion word with *

Comment: @Olle: aha right, I guess I didn't notice that your first query used the - (minus) operator as in '-banana*'. Well from what I understand, your first query must not return any results either. Even if you do '+bananas -b*' it will not return any results. I tried out a test run on my dev and I found that a search on (+philippines) returned results but (+philippines -ph*) returned none.